# previous button shows validations

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

This is an example of my textbox in my form with a custom validation, I want to disable the validators :

```
 <asp:textbox id="txtFirstName" runat="server" /></td><td>
        <script language ="javascript">
            function requireFirstName(source, args) {

                if (document.getElementById("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>").value =="") {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                }
                else {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                }
            }
      </script>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="RequiredValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="You must enter your first name." 
             ForeColor="Red" clientvalidationfunction="requireFirstName"
            ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

This is my previous button:

```
<asp:Button ID="PreviousButton" runat="server"  
                Text="<-- Back to Instructions" OnClick="btnBack_Click" 
                class="previous"   />
            <script type="javascript">
             document.getElementById("<%=PreviousButton.ClientID%>").disableValidation = true;
            </script>
```

This will not work and still has validators..help

Comment: This's not necesary: if (document.getElementById("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>").value ==""). You can use: if (args.Value =="")

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Button ID="PreviousButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"  
                Text="<-- Back to Instructions" OnClick="btnBack_Click" 
                class="previous" EnableClientScript="false"   />
```

Comment: try adding this; EnableClientScript="false" as above.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx) to false.

```
<asp:Button ID="PreviousButton" runat="server" Text="<-- Back to Instructions" OnClick="btnBack_Click" class="previous" CausesValidation="false" />
```